# EF Core 6 + SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2 - code first): BLOB data type couldn't be found

Tags: c#, blob, ef-core-6.0

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class CustomerData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID = Guid.Empty;

    [Required]
    [Column("Data", TypeName = "BLOB")]
    public byte[]? Data { get; set; } = null;
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CustomerData> CustomerData { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerData>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ID).HasName("ID");
        });
    }
}
```

In package manager console:

```
    add-migration v1
    Build started ...
    Build succeeded.
    update-database
    Build started ...
    Build succeeded.

    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
        Entity Framework Core 6.0.5 initialized 'MyDbContext' using 
        provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.5' with options: None
    ...
    fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
          Failed executing DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[], 
          CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          CREATE TABLE [CustomerData] (
              [ID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
              [Data] BLOB NOT NULL,
              CONSTRAINT [ID] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
          );

    Failed executing DbCommand (3ms) 
        [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
    CREATE TABLE [CustomerData] (
        [ID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        [Data] BLOB NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [ID] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
    );
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
        The BLOB data type for the column, the parameter 
        or the variable no. "2" couldn't be found.
```

How do I teach EF core 6 to properly handle my BLOB property and create the appropriate table in my SQL Server database?

Comment: By not using `BLOB`, since that's not a SQL Server type. :P You seem to be looking for `VARBINARY(MAX)` (though I honestly would expect that to be the default for a `byte[]` property with no explicit type, but I have no experience with EF in that regard).

Comment: Note also that marking the property `Required` and then also making it nullable seems just ever so slightly contradictory. Consider declaring it as `public byte[] Data { get; set; } = Array.Empty<byte>();`, or else removing the `Required`.

Comment: @Jeroen: Well, BLOB is an SQL data type to my knowledge, but I didn't know whether MS SQL had a different name for it, and couldn't find anything by googling. As far as "required" goes: There must always be defined data for that column in the db table, but not necessarily in the app. I just didn't know Array.Empty<T> exists. I am coming from C++, and while my C# knowledge is quite solid, there are probably many details I am not aware of. Thanks for your pointers. :)